# ASP Net core некорректный ответ функции из Postgresql

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, asp.net-core

Стоит задача получить все сообщения из бесед ВК и запихнуть их в базу данных. Но, предположим, в таблице уже есть некоторые сообщения из беседы. В моем случае их 53
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каждое сообщение имеет `Primary Key` - `ID` сообщения.
И, очевидно, если попытаться добавить сообщение с уже имеющимся `ID` в таблице, то ничего хорошего не будет.

Я написал функцию, в которую на вход идет массив `ID` (массив `ID` полученных с сервера ВК всех сообщений из конкретной беседы).
И по идее функция должна искать уже существующие в таблице `ID` сообщений:

#### Код функции

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION exists_messages(bigint[]) RETURNS SETOF bigint AS
$$
DECLARE
      ids ALIAS FOR $1;
      rec     RECORD;
BEGIN
      FOR rec IN SELECT "Id" FROM "Messages" WHERE "Id" = ANY(ids)
      LOOP
              RETURN NEXT rec;
      END LOOP;
      -- final return
      RETURN;
END
$$ language plpgsql;
```

И все бы хорошо, да вот только на бэкэнд приходит ровно на один `ID` меньше, чем есть в таблице:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И я уже не знаю что делать. Тесты вручную проводил, но с куда меньшим количеством `ID`, поскольку не запихнешь же в терминал 27 тыс. значений.

#### Код вызова функции

```
public List<long?> ExistsMessages(List<long?> ids)
        {
            var connection = Database.GetDbConnection();
            using (var command = connection.CreateCommand() )
            {
                if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    connection.Open();
                
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.CommandText = "exists_messages";
                    
            var idsParam = command.CreateParameter();
            idsParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            idsParam.Value = ids;
            
            command.Parameters.Add(idsParam);

            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            List<long?> result = new List<long?>();
            
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var _ids = reader.Cast<IDataRecord>().Select(x => x.GetInt64(0));
                result.AddRange(_ids.Cast<long?>());
            }
            
            if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                connection.Close();
            
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: В бекенд приходит на одно меньше. Ну, допустим. А откуда отправляете? Я вообще не вижу ничего в вопросе про то, откуда "пули вытелели". Из базы летит? Из фронтенда? Вам наверное всё понятно в вопросе, стороннему человеку - не очень.

Comment: @AK, а код вызова функции не? Или вы про что? `ids` идут на вход в функцию на бэкэнде `ExistsMessages(List<long?> ids)`. А про их путь до этой функции писать бесполезно -- никому не интересно и не нужно. Из функции на бэкэнде вызывается функция на sql сервере с теми параметрами, что передали в функцию на бэкэнде. Чего тут непонятного то?

Comment: Почему приходит на одно значение меньше - ничего сказать не могу. Однако, мне непонятно, зачем такой сложный (имхо) способ? Я бы просто вставлял сообщения стандартным способом по одному с помощью sql-запроса `insert`. Ключи разные, значит вставится - хорошо. Ключи совпали - выбросится исключение, пропускаем его, переходим к следующему.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, а разве это красиво? Как минимум, насколько мне известно, после каждого исключения вызывается `rollback()`, что тоже занимает время и память. Немного, но должно быть заметно на дистанции (лично мое мнение, подкреплено здравым смыслом)

Comment: Допустим, ваш способ заработал. Вы получили список имеющихся в таблице сообщений. В этот момент другой поток/процесс вставил в таблицу какое-то сообщение. Теперь ваш поток/процесс продолжил работу и пытается вставить сообщения и ловит исключение, потому что id совпал с тем, который вставил другой поток/процесс. Вся проверка пошла насмарку. Уж сколько об этом писали: нет смысла делать предварительные проверки, есть ли запись в БД. Потому что это надёжно работает только в том случае, если с БД работает **единственный** клиент.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, а я не говорил, что я не единственный клиент :D; К слову обработка исключений и так стоит, но банально жалко что функция не работает. Разберусь с ней все равно.

Comment: Откуда возьмётся rollback? Только в том случае, если все вставки обернуть в транзакцию. Но если делать insert без общей транзакции, то ошибка при вставке одного сообщения никак не повлияет на другие.

Comment: Я понимаю, разобраться в чём-то всегда интересно. Я с постгресом почти не работал, поэтому в данном случае помочь не смогу. Желаю успеха!